# How to add a unicode symbol to a submit button

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I would like to add a unicode to the text of a SubmitField.

For instance, the code

```
submit = SubmitField('&#9993; Send')
```

does not work. How can I change that to show this envelope unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the unicode codepoint in a `\uhhhh` escape sequence, there is no need to use HTML escapes:

```
submit = SubmitField('\u2709 Send')
```

or even the codepoint itself:

```
submit = SubmitField('✉ Send')
```

The string value produced is exactly the same.

The label is quoted to ensure proper handling in HTML, so any `&` characters in the label value are encoded to `&amp;`, breaking your `&#9993;` reference.