# How to add a html <span> to the SubmitField text argument?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to include an envelope symbol to the submit button text.

Basically the code that I want to generate is

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Envelope</button>
```

[reference](https://www.jquery-az.com/boots/demo.php?ex=12.0_8)

But of course I can't do

```
submit = SubmitField('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Send')
```

What is the best approach to do this? I am trying some javascript code, but I think this is not the best idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my reading of the wtforms code, the generic SubmitField renders an HTML element that looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="SOME TEXT LABEL">
```

The reason it does this is because `SubmitField` has the signature (you can trace the inheritance to see the HTML generation code):

```
class SubmitField(BooleanField):
    """
    Represents an ``<input type="submit">``.  This allows checking if a given
    submit button has been pressed.
    """
    widget = widgets.SubmitInput()
```

To output the HTML as you want you need to define a custom widget. Look up the documentation on this.

For example something like this (untested) might work:

```
class MySubmitWidget(widgets.SubmitInput): # note subclassing the original
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):  # but overriding the render
        return HTMLString('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Envelope</button>')

class MySubmitField(SubmitField): # note subclassing the original
    widget = MySubmitWidget # but overriding the render widget
```

And in your form you just use `MySubmitField` instead. If you want to customise further or make the HTML dynamic you have to modify the `__call__()` method to generate HTML responsive to `kwargs`.

Note, however that `<input type="submit">` elements have a particular default action that is to submit a form, when you render a generic `<button>` it wont automatically submit your form so you will most likely have to solve that problem next.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

In the form definition, mention this for submit field.

submit = SubmitField('✉')

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, but in this case, I am wondering to know how to include an HTML. The envelope itself is just one example. But actually, I had this problem here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879634/how-to-add-a-unicode-symbol-to-a-submit-button/55879665#55879665)